# create more than five tables in SQLite database on android studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a problem with creating more than three tables in the android studio `SQLite database`. I read more than 50 comments, watch videos but didn't help me... I followed one video that almost assist me but in my DatabaseManager class there is an error. once I run the project here is an error after the project build

```
"error: cannot find symbol class illegalStateException"
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, please post your code in your question to show what you've tried so far and what you're struggling with

Comment: You need to include the stack-trace (edit your question to include it) to show where the exception happened in addition to the code (see [Debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug)). The message on it's own indicates very little.